# Simultaneous assignment in Python matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, assign

When I execute the code below

```
    A = [[None] * 3] * 3
    print(A)
    A[0][0] = 1
    print(A)
```

The two prints return

```
    [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
    [[1, None, None], [1, None, None], [1, None, None]]
```

The statement `A[0][0] = 1` assigns the value `1` to `A[0][0]`, `A[1][0]`, and `A[2][0]` instead of just assigning it to `A[0][0]`. Why is this the case?

Comment: You have the same reference inside `A` - check them with `print(id(A[0]))` and `print(id(A[1]))`. Use `A = [[None for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]` - never use the `A = [[None] * 3] * 3` syntax to create nested lists